# Capturing a closure in JavaScript after-the-fact

Tags: javascript, closures, global

I have a 3rd party JavaScript application that declares several global functions and needs some variables to be defined for those functions to work. I would rather not define those variables in the global scope. Here's an example:

Suppose you have a globally defined function `foo` that prints out the value of an externally-defined variable named `x`.

```
function foo() {
    console.log(x);
}
```

I think the only way for `x` to have a value within `foo` is if `x` is also a global. I hope I'm wrong. What I would really like to do is this:

```
(function () {
    var x = 'someValue';
    var bar = magicallyFixSoXIsntGlobal(foo);
    bar();
}());
```

I guess I could do:

```
(function () {
    var x = 'someValue';
    var bar = Function(foo.toString());
    bar();
}());
```

But that seems pretty much like `eval`. (If it comes down to that, I'd rather have global spam than use eval.)

Is there any way to "fix" the global functions so they can refer to the enclosed values?

Comment: Or if `foo()` and `x` are both in the same execution context, like that closure, `foo()` can reference `x`.  But I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do?  You've got a 3rd party function running which is relying on values in the global context, but you want it to run in a closure so everything is excluded from the global context?

Comment: You cannot change a function's execution context (what variables resolve to) after it is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a value to a `window`'s property, call the function, then use the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator to truly remove the variable.

```
window.foo = 'bar';
magic();
delete window.foo; // Because `foo` is defined without `var`, it can be deleted
```

Comment: If `window.foo` has already been defined, a local scope can be created by using an anonymous function: `(function(local_foo){window.foo='bar';magic();window.foo=local_foo;})(window.foo)`

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is to modify `foo` to take `x` as a variable. But, assuming you can't / don't want to do that, I can think of two options:

- declare `x` as a global variable.
- Wrap `foo`'s declaration in a closure.

The first will certainly make `foo` work, but please don't take Rob W's approach. Remember that the reason people tell you "don't clutter the global namespace" isn't because they're worried about unused variables hanging around (that can be a problem, but it's not specific to the global namespace). It's because having multiple functions using the same namespace increases the chances that one will overwrite the other's variables. Here's how you would use the global `x` without bludgeoning the rest of your code.

```
!function(x, exists) {
  window.x=10;
  foo();

  if(exists)
    window.x=x;
  else
    delete window.x;
}(window.x, 'x' in window);
```

The second option shouldn't be too hard if `foo` is currently just a `function` declaration within your code. In that case, change it to:

```
!function() {
  var x=10;
  function foo() {
    [...]
  }
  // foo can only be called within this block
}();
```

Or if `foo` must be global, but you still don't want x to be global:

```
!function() {
  var x=10;
  window.foo=function() {
    [...]
  };
  // now foo can be called anywhere, and will still use the x declared above
}();
```

But if foo is included via an external script then it gets more complicated, and I don't think you could use this method without modifying `foo`. (You could also use ajax and `eval`, or just `eval`, but I think you're right in avoiding that function.)

Comment: When you do `var x = 10; function(x){`, `x=10` is not accessible from within the function, because it's locally declared & defined again. `with` does not work like that. `{x:10}` does not have any influence on code outside the `with`, so it will not solve the scoping issue:  http://jsfiddle.net/xbwxv/. Only the first method could work.

Comment: `function(x)` was a typo, thanks for catching that. As for `with`, yes, I know. But that's ok in this case, as kojiro specified that `foo` doesn't change `x`, only prints it.

Comment: Well, that's odd. I guess I should have tested that more carefully. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The question features 3rd-party JavaScript that I cannot easily change. Thus, having `x` as a global variable seems to be my only option for now. I am going to try to modify the provided JavaScript so it uses parameters instead of global variables and send it back to the vendor, but there's no guarantee they'll take it.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. Just a side-note - if you really want to be sure you're leaving `x` the way you found it, you also need to determine if it had been declared and delete it if it hadn't. My code got close to doing that before, but I made a slight change so it also works if it had been assigned to `undefined` (or declared but not assigned).

Answer (score 0):

This is what function parameters are for

```
function foo(x) {
  console.log(x)
}
```

You could hack it horrible if you wanted by converting the function to a string and creating a new function which accepts parameters, but that's dirty as hell